# Populating a 7x7 grid based on inner 5x5 values

Tags: algorithm

I am here trying to find help with an algorithm.

I have a 7x7 grid of integers which follows two rules sets:
The first rule set (which I have successfully programmed) states:

The number one (1) is to be randomly placed in the inner 5x5 grid. Using the placement of (1), populate the rest of the inner 5x5 grid such that consecutive numbers are adjacent (vertically, horizontally, or diagonally).

This part I've already done, I have a program that can populate the inner 5x5 grid based on the placement of (1) while avoiding locking itself out of other grid spots. Here is an example of the inner 5x5 grid generated by my program (outer square marked with "o" for clarity):

```
o|o |o |o |o |o |o
o|8 |9 |10|14|15|o
o|7 |11|13|17|16|o
o|6 |12|18|20|21|o
o|1 |5 |19|22|23|o
o|2 |3 |4 |24|25|o
o|o |o |o |o |o |o
```

The second rule set states:
The outer square of the 7x7 grid must then be populated by the numbers 2 - 25, such that any number Y within the inner grid falls within the same row, column, or diagonal (diagonal in an "X" through the center only) as Y in the outer ring.

I am posting here as a last resort. I have spent around 20 hours looking at this second rule set, have tried several attempts at a solution (at best I end up with 4 empty spaces in the outer ring) and I feel like I'm hitting a brick wall here. Is there an algorithm for this that I'm just not seeing? Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no C++ involved in the question here, which is the reason I removed the tag. Algorithms are inherently language-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The below is not very elegant. I suggest it only because it's fairly quick and easy to implement, and because if you've spent 20 hours without making progress then I'm guessing you're not going to be so picky about an inelegant solution. :-P

---

The second rule set doesn't really depend on the values of the numbers at all, other than `1`; as far as it cares, (e.g.) `17` is just a meaningless label that needs to be copied.

So, to save some distraction, you can think of your example grid as this:

```
o|o|o|o|o|o|o
o|A|B|C|D|E|o
o|F|G|H|I|J|o
o|K|L|M|N|O|o
o|1|Q|R|S|T|o
o|U|V|W|X|Y|o
o|o|o|o|o|o|o
```

where your goal is to copy `A` through `Y` (except `1`) in the way specified by the second rule set.

Furthermore, the second rule set is very symmetric; if you write a `flip_horizontal` function and a `flip_vertical` function and a `transpose` function, then there are really only six distinct positions that the `1` could possibly be in:

```
o|o|o|o|o|o|o
o| | | | | |o
o| | | | | |o
o|1|1|1| | |o
o|1|1| | | |o
o|1| | | | |o
o|o|o|o|o|o|o
```

So, what you can do is:

1. Manually solve each of the six possible distinct cases, which as a human isn't so hard. For example, the above example:

   ```
   o|o|o|o|o|o|o
   o|A|B|C|D|E|o
   o|F|G|H|I|J|o
   o|K|L|M|N|O|o
   o|1|Q|R|S|T|o
   o|U|V|W|X|Y|o
   o|o|o|o|o|o|o
   ```

   has this solution:

   ```
   A|F|G|C|N|J|E
   B|A|B|C|D|E|D
   H|F|G|H|I|J|I
   L|K|L|M|N|O|O
   Q|1|Q|R|S|T|R
   U|U|V|W|X|Y|X
   M|K|V|W|S|T|Y
   ```

   (I recommend doing this in a text editor, and blanking out letters as you go so that you can easily see what's left to do. You don't have to be terribly systematic about it; guess-and-check, plus tweaking when you run into problems, should suffice. And for that matter, you can use the above example as a starting-point for at least a few of the other cases.)
2. For each of those six cases, write a function that handles that case. Each of these functions can literally just be twenty-four lines of things like `array[4][0] = array[3][2];`. It's not exciting, but it will work.
3. Write a function that checks if `1` is in an acceptable position. If so, it invokes the appropriate function from step #2; if not, it calls an appropriate `flip`-function, then calls itself recursively, then calls the same `flip`-function again to restore the original positions.
4. Write a test program that executes your total algorithm (both rule sets) for all twenty-five possible positions of `1` and validates that the result always satisfies both rule-sets. (This is important both because testing is always important, and more specifically because it'd be very easy to miss a typo somewhere in step #2.)